# How to disable rspec's checking for access to double outside of original example?

Tags: ruby, rspec

A class double is created in a `let` which is accessed by multiple examples. For example:

```rb
let(:foo_klass) do
  class_double('A::B::C::Foo')
end
```

Other unit tests use `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class)` to examine the classes to select, for example, all modules including another module:

```rb
  def find_modules_including_module(target_module)
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select do |object|
      # All Class'es are modules, but we are not interested in them, so we exclude them.
      !object.is_a?(Class) \
        && \
        object.ancestors.include?(target_module) \
        && \
        !object.equal?(target_module)
    end
  end
```

It is only the unit tests that call `find_modules_including_module` that fail. The error looks something like this:

```
     Failure/Error: object.ancestors.include?(target_module) \
       #<ClassDouble(MyModule::MyClass) (anonymous)> was originally created in one example but has leaked into another example and can no longer be used. rspec-mocks' doubles are designed to only last for one example, and you need to create a new one in each example you wish to use it for.
```

I understand why failing on any access on the double class is almost always the right thing to do, but mine is a special case in which that behavior is problematic and IMO inappropriate.

Is there an option to suppress this temporarily? Or do you have another suggestion?

---

In response to @engineersmnky's comments, and to provide context, I am adding the following:

I am doing this whole exercise because I am using the SemanticLogger logging gem, which provides a Loggable module which provides a class method and an instance method named 'logger'. The instance method calls the class method (`self.class.logger`).

If a module (let's call it `M`) includes Loggable, and a class (let's call it `C`) includes `M`, then C will assimilate M's instance method as if it were its own. When it is called, it will try to get `self.class.logger`, but `self` is the C instance and not the module, and since there is no C class method `logger`, a NoMethodError is raised.

My solution is to add this to every module that includes `Loggable`:

```
def self.included(klass)
  klass.class_exec do
    include SemanticLogger::Loggable
  end
end
```

This works, but there is a risk that in the future a new module will include `Loggable` but not this `included` implementation. I want to be able to detect this situation programmatically in a test. My current test looks like this:

```
  specify 'all classes including modules that include Loggable include Loggable themselves' do
    modules_including_loggable = modules_including_module(SemanticLogger::Loggable)
    classes_including_those_modules = classes_including_modules(modules_including_loggable)
    suspicious_classes = classes_not_having_ancestor(classes_including_those_modules, SemanticLogger::Loggable)
    expect(suspicious_classes.map(&:name).sort.join("\n")).to eq('')
  end
```

The methods used are defined as follows:

```
  def modules_including_module(target_module)
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select do |object|
      # All Class'es are modules, but we are not interested in them, so we exclude them.
      !object.is_a?(Class) \
        && \
        object.ancestors.include?(target_module) \
        && \
        !object.equal?(target_module)
    end
  end

  def classes_including_modules(modules)
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select do |klass|
      (klass.ancestors & modules).any?
    end
  end

  def classes_not_having_ancestor(classes, ancestor)
    classes.select do |klass|
      !klass.ancestors.include?(ancestor)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code that is causing this?

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for asking. I've reworded the question somewhat and added more/better code examples to clarify the question.

Comment: That is going to be a tough one to solve and I am surprised it didn't raise an issue on the first call `object.is_a?(Class)`. Is there a specific reason you are going about it in this fashion rather than tracking the inclusion in the "target_module" itself?

Comment: @engineersmnky Can you explain what you mean by "tracking the inclusion in the target module itself"?

Comment: The purpose of this code appears to be to determine what Modules include a given module. The `Module` class offers a hook that runs when it is included in another object. It is possible you could leverage this hook to manage the including objects within the target_module itself. I am not aware of the scope, scale, or purpose of the code contained in `find_modules_including_module` so I cannot definitively state that this is the solution.

Comment: Additionally if you are continuing down your current path; rather than using the ancestral chain I would recommend using `Module#included_modules` as this will limit the list returned to just Modules included in the `object`